# nginx loopback reverse proxy can't access custom paths

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy, loopback

Im running this loopback app in my server and trying to access it through an nginx reverse proxy, but can't seem to get nginx configured correctly, I'm a total noob to nginx. Here's my config file **/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  server_name example.com;
  server_name _;
  root /apps/example/client;

  location ~ ^/.well-known {
    allow all;
  }
  location / {
    return 301 https://example.com;
  }
}
server {
        server_name example.com;
        server_name www.example.com;
        #listen 80;
        # SSL configuration
        listen 443 ssl ;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;

        root /apps/example/client;

        # Check Alive
        location ~ ^/.well-known {
             allow all;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_bind 127.0.0.1;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
        }

        location /api {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/api;
        }
        location /explorer {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/explorer;
        }

}
```

and my loopback server serves static files like this:
`app.use(loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client')));`

and at the end of my server.js file I serve the index.html file for any path not processed so angular processes that path in the front end

```
function startsWith(string, array) {
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    if(string.startsWith(array[i]))
      return true;
  return false;
}
let ignoredPaths = ['/css', '/fonts', '/img', '/js', '/lib', '/sfx', '/views', '/api'];

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  //Redirecting to index only the requests that do not start with ignored paths
  console.log("Requested url: ",req.url);
  if(!startsWith(req.url, ignoredPaths)) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'client')});
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

The issue is that I can only access `http://www.example.com/` and it takes a lot to load and the url flashes many times like it's redirecting a lot of times, I redirect in front-end with angular to `/home`, I have the angular routing to use html5 to remove the `/#!/` from the path, but I always get a Bad Gateway error if I try to access any other path, say `http://www.example.com/admin/login` and it's a nginx error, it's not reaching loopback so it can serve the index file. I've tried the `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` but if I try to access any other custom path, say `/auth/facebook` it forces it to load it through `index.html` and that's a custom path I have setup on loopback to do special behaviour. I have no idea how to solve this, I just used that template config file, all I need is for it to redirect all requests from `example.com` to my app in `localhost:3000` and do the same in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

So i kept trying, and tried again using the `try_files` with a @path (I guess that's kind of a label or something) and what I was missing when I tried it before was to attach `$uri` at the end of the `proxy_pass`
It ended up like this:

```
location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_bind 127.0.0.1;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
        }
location @proxy {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_bind 127.0.0.1;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000$uri;
        }
```

And all works dandy now :P.